# PHP delete in CRUD will not remove item from the database

Tags: php, mysql, crud, sql-delete

I am new to stackoverflow and this is my first question on this platform:
my delete.php file will give me a "record deleted" message however, the item is not removed from my sql database
this is my code! can you guys spot anything wrong with this?

```
<?php
require_once "pdo.php";
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['user_id'])){
    $sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id= :zip";
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':zip' =>$_POST['user_id']));
    $_SESSION['success']='Record Deleted';
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;}
    

$stmt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT name, user_id from users where user_id= :xyz");
$stmt->execute(array(":xyz"=>$_GET['user_id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($row===false){
    $_SESSION['error']="bad value for user id";
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;}
?>
<p>Confirm Deleting <?=htmlentities($row['name'])?></p>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?$row['user_id']?>">
<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete">
<a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$stmt->affected_rows` after the `$stmt->execute()` call when deleting a row? What is the return value of `$stmt->execute()`?

Comment: I am sorry i am very new to programming your question made no sense to me :)

Comment: $stmt->execute() returns either true or false (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).  Check that return value like Progman was saying.  If it's false you can use other PDO methods to look at the error message.

Comment: hi thanks for ur help, it returns true i also added a print_r and it clearly shows the row selected as the correct row !

Answer (score 1):

for those interested in knowing what was wrong with the code:

```
"<?$row['user_id']?>"
```

was changed to

```
"<?=$row['user_id']?>"
```

thanks !